# How do you call a C function that takes (or returns) a struct by value from JS via Emscripen/Wasm?

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten, webassembly

Passing structs, arrays, and strings by reference from Javascript to C is pretty well documented in the Emscripten docs (https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-direct-function-calls).

But what about passing structures by value?  If I have a C function like this:

```
typedef struct {double a, b, c;} MyStruct;

MyStruct Foo(const MyStruct x, double y);
```

How would I call Foo and decode the result? (Either using Module.cwrap or calling Module._Foo directly).  Would I need to get access to the Emscripten stack to do that? Where is that documented?

Answer (score 9):

`Module._malloc()`, `Module.writeArrayToMemory()` and `Module.ccall()` is available, but it's very complicated.

It is easier to wrap it with C++ and embind.

```
// em++ --bind test.cpp -o test.js
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;

struct MyStruct {
  double a, b, c;
};

MyStruct Foo(const MyStruct x, double y) {
  MyStruct r;
  r.a = x.a;
  r.b = x.b;
  r.c = y;
  return r;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_struct) {
  class_<MyStruct>("MyStruct")
    .constructor<>()
    .property("a", &MyStruct::a)
    .property("b", &MyStruct::b)
    .property("c", &MyStruct::c)
    ;

  function("Foo", &Foo);
}
```

And call from JavaScript.

```
var x = new Module.MyStruct();
x.a = 10;
x.b = 20;
x.c = 30;
var y = Module.Foo(x, 21);
console.log(y, y.a, y.b, y.c);

x.delete();
y.delete();
```

---

Also you can [allocate memory on stack](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/advanced-apis.html#allocate), and `ccall`.

```
var sp = Module.Runtime.stackSave();
var ret = Module.allocate(24, 'i8', Module.ALLOC_STACK);
var ptr_a = Module.allocate(24, 'i8', Module.ALLOC_STACK);
Module.HEAPF64[(ptr_a >> 3) + 0] = Math.random();
Module.HEAPF64[(ptr_a >> 3) + 1] = Math.random();
Module.HEAPF64[(ptr_a >> 3) + 2] = Math.random();
Module.ccall("Foo",
             'number',
             ['number', 'number', 'number'],
             [ret, ptr_a, 21]
            );
console.log(
    sp,
    Module.HEAPF64[(ret >> 3) + 0],
    Module.HEAPF64[(ret >> 3) + 1],
    Module.HEAPF64[(ret >> 3) + 2]);
Module.Runtime.stackRestore(sp);
```

Comment: I don't really want write a wrapper (this is huge C interface, so would be a pain).  If I do that I might as well write a wrapper that passes by reference. Any idea what the Embind is doing under the hood that allows passing by value? (or is it just passing by reference under the hood)

Comment: And writeArrayToMemory and _malloc only helps if you are passing by reference, right? You can't pass by value without getting access to the stack, or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps returning structure by value is calling convention dependent.

Comment: Oh your edit above looks to be exactly what I'm after, thanks. I will try it (though I have now gone through and added wrapper functions that pass by reference).  You are quite right it, however I will need to take into account the cdecl calling conventions which may have some gotchas.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible and here how it works:

1. When C structure is **passed by value**, it is proceeded as if it is passed by pointer.

Structure:

```c
typedef struct {
    size_t a;
    double b;
} my_struct_t;
```

Pass by value (C):

```c
size_t my_struct_get_a(my_struct_t my) {
    return my.a;
}
```

Pass by value (Wasm):

```
  (func $func3 (param $var0 i32) (result i32)
    get_local $var0
    i32.load
  )
```

Pass by pointer (C):

```c
size_t my_struct_ptr_get_a(const my_struct_t* my) {
    return my->a;
}
```

Pass by pointer (Wasm):

```
  (func $func5 (param $var0 i32) (result i32)
    get_local $var0
    i32.load
  )
```

**WebAssembly code is the same!**

2. When C structure is **returned by value**, then it is expected to be passed as a first function parameter!

Return by value (C):

```c
my_struct_t my_struct_create(size_t a, double b) {
    return (my_struct_t){a, b};
}
```

Return by value (Wasm):

```
  (func $func1 (param $var0 i32) (param $var1 i32) (param $var2 f64)
    get_local $var0
    get_local $var2
    f64.store offset=8
    get_local $var0
    get_local $var1
    i32.store
  )
```

Pay attention that Wasm does not contain `result` and has 3 `param`s.

For comparison lets check alternative function:

```c
void my_struct_fill(my_struct_t* my, size_t a, double b) {
    my->a = a;
    my->b = b;
}
```

Wasm is equal to the previous function:

```
  (func $func2 (param $var0 i32) (param $var1 i32) (param $var2 f64)
    get_local $var0
    get_local $var2
    f64.store offset=8
    get_local $var0
    get_local $var1
    i32.store
  )
```

[Full C code sample and its Wasm](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/?state=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22showGutter%22%3Atrue%2C%22showConsole%22%3Atrue%2C%22showOptions%22%3Atrue%2C%22autoCompile%22%3Atrue%2C%22showLLVM%22%3Afalse%2C%22darkMode%22%3Atrue%2C%22fastMath%22%3Afalse%2C%22noInline%22%3Afalse%2C%22noRTTI%22%3Afalse%2C%22noExceptions%22%3Afalse%2C%22cleanWast%22%3Atrue%2C%22wasmBaseline%22%3Afalse%2C%22dialect%22%3A%22C99%22%2C%22optimizationLevel%22%3A%22s%22%7D%2C%22source%22%3A%22%23include%20%3Cstddef.h%3E%5Cn%5Cntypedef%20struct%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20size_t%20a%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20double%20b%3B%5Cn%7D%20my_struct_t%3B%5Cn%5Cnsize_t%20my_struct_size(void)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20sizeof(my_struct_t)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnmy_struct_t%20my_struct_create(size_t%20a%2C%20double%20b)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20(my_struct_t)%7Ba%2C%20b%7D%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnvoid%20my_struct_fill(my_struct_t*%20my%2C%20size_t%20a%2C%20double%20b)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20my-%3Ea%20%3D%20a%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20my-%3Eb%20%3D%20b%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnsize_t%20my_struct_get_a(my_struct_t%20my)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20my.a%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cndouble%20my_struct_get_b(my_struct_t%20my)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20my.b%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnsize_t%20my_struct_ptr_get_a(const%20my_struct_t%20*my)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20my-%3Ea%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cndouble%20my_struct_ptr_get_b(const%20my_struct_t%20*my)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20my-%3Eb%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D)

Note, this approach works well for WebAssembly, asm.js was not checked.